# Alternative to [ -z $var ] on empty pipe?

Tags: bash

I'm working on a script to make Alacritty drop-down (or Quake mode, if you prefer) on my desktop and was planning to unmap its window when it looses focus.

I've been trying to wrap my brain around using the window ID to get the focused state directly, but the problem with that is that X doesn't seem to use a value for a windows' unfocused state.
My first try was this:

```
xprop -spy -id "$wid" | grep --line-buffered "_NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED" |
while read -r focused; do
    if [[ -z $focused ]]; then
        echo "off"
    fi
done
```

But I quickly realized that `while read` quits on me if it gets an empty pipe.

I want to run a command as soon as the window is no longer focused, but at that point the pipe that checks for focus gets terminated and the conditions to run a command disappears.

I'm curious to know if there is any way of making something like this to work, or if it's just a hard no.

EDIT:
It was pointed out that my post was a bit ambiguous.
Is there any way of using `xprop -spy` to continuously check if a window *hasn't* state "_NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED" set?

Comment: `while read quits on me if it gets an empty pipe.` empty pipe means it is closed, the end, nothing more to read. I can get `xprop -spy` to end the stream when the window is closed. Dunno what exactly would you want to check in that case. Also, how is `focused` supposed to be empty `-z` if you know that it will contain the line `grep "_NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED"`?

Comment: The window isn't closed though. I'm trying to check if it isn't focused.

Comment: Then the pipe is not empty. I believe you meant that you want to read an empty _line_ from the pipe. Empty line is still something in the pipe, pipe not empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
if xprop -id "$wid" | grep -q '_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED'; then
    echo on
else
    echo off
fi
```

To monitor the loss of focus, you use `root` window :

```
xprop -spy -root | { 
having_focus=
while read line; do
    grep -q "_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING(WINDOW)"<<<"$line"||continue
    line=${line##* }
    if test "$line" = "$wid"; then
        if test "$having_focus" != 1; then
            having_focus=1
            echo "Window [$wid] has got  focus."
        fi  
    else
        if test "$having_focus" = 1; then
            having_focus=0
            echo "Window [$wid] has lost focus."
        fi  
    fi  
done
}
```

Make sure `$wid` is in hexadecimal form like 0x340001e.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I want to run a command as soon as the window is no longer focused, but at that point the pipe that checks for focus gets terminated and the conditions to run a command disappears.

Comment: @EduardoIslaVenegas Well, yes. `foo | ...` is going to give an EOF on the stdin of `...` after `foo` exits and its stdout has been closed. Do you expect to get around that somehow? (To be clear, you _can_ get around it, for example by having your program consist of more than just this one pipeline, or having the left-hand side of the pipe restart `foo` after it exits; none of these involve finding alternatives to `test -z`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think I worded the title wrong. What I meant was an alternative to what I was using [ -z $var ] for. What I wanted was to monitor the status of the windows for "_NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED", and as soon as it disappears, run a command. But now I'm thinking that I'm just trying to solve my problem the wrong way.

Comment: @Philippe I'm using something similar at the moment. I just thought that if you could monitor for _NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED's being or not being, it would be a more elegant solution. But I might just be asking for a solution that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

> Alternative to [ -z $var ] on empty pipe?

Check the exit status of `read` on the first line.

```
.... |
{
   if ! IFS= read -r line; then
       echo empty pipe
   fi
   printf "%s\n" "$line"
   cat
} |
...
```

> Is there any way of using xprop -spy to continuously check if a window hasn't state "_NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED" set?

Just parse the `xprop` output. I found that lines with `_NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED` start with `_NET_WM_STATE`.

```
xprop -spy -id "$wid" |
while IFS=' ' read -r what eq val; do
   if [[ "$what" == _NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) && "$eq" == "=" && "$val" != "_NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED" ]]; then
         echo off
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The problem I have with the last part though, is that the windows can have a varying number of states. The one in question is sometimes sticky. That's why I was trying to target _NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED specifically.